# No video mode large enough error in pygame when using 1,8" TFT via a RPi

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, sdl

First off i just want to mention that i'm not actually sure that this questions is asked on the correct StackExchange, since it is a lot of different topics involved i might need to ask it somewhere else. I do believe it boils down to a problem somewhere between Python (`pygame`) and SDL.

**What i've done:**

1. I've hooked up a Sainsmart 1,8" TFT to my Raspberry Pi running on a
   MINIBIAN image (a small footprint version of Raspbian), i've got the
   TFT to work since i can send console output to it and display images
   using `fbi` (writes directly to the frame buffer).
2. Installed and loaded the [fbtft](https://github.com/notro/fbtft) drivers (*Linux Framebuffer drivers for small TFT LCD display modules*)

From `dmesg`:

`[   12.377397] graphics fb1: fb_st7735r frame buffer, 128x160, 40 KiB video memory, 4 KiB DMA buffer memory, fps=20, spi0.0 at 32 MHz`

**The problem:**

What i now want to test is to display a clock on my TFT using `pygame`, the code i've got is (borrowed from http://gerfficient.com/2014/02/12/connecting-1-8-tft-lcd-to-raspberry-pi/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import time
import pygame

time_stamp_prev=0

os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']="fbcon"

def displaytext(text,size,line,color,clearscreen):
   if clearscreen:
       screen.fill((0,0,0))

   font = pygame.font.Font(None,size)
   text = font.render(text,0,color)
   rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(text,90)
   textpos = rotated.get_rect()
   textpos.centery = 80
   if line == 1:
        textpos.centerx = 99
        screen.blit(rotated,textpos)
   elif line == 2:
        textpos.centerx = 61
        screen.blit(rotated,textpos)
   elif line == 3:
        textpos.centerx = 25
        screen.blit(rotated,textpos)

def main():
    global screen

    pygame.init()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    size = width,height = 128,160
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    while True:
        displaytext(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y",time.gmtime()),40,1,(255,255,255),True)
        displaytext(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime()),40,2,(255,255,255),False)
        displaytext("gerfficient.com",20,3,(100,100,255),False)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error i get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    pygame.display.set_mode()
pygame.error: No video mode large enough for 128x160
```

When i'm displaying more info via `pygame` and run `print pygame.display.Info()` i get:

```
<VideoInfo(hw = 1, wm = 0,video_mem = 40
             blit_hw = 0, blit_hw_CC = 0, blit_hw_A = 0,
             blit_sw = 0, blit_sw_CC = 0, blit_sw_A = 0,
             bitsize  = 16, bytesize = 2,
             masks =  (63488, 2016, 31, 0),
             shifts = (11, 5, 0, 0),
             losses =  (3, 2, 3, 8),
             current_w = 128, current_h = 160
>
```

Output of `fbset -i -fb /dev/fb1`:

```
mode "128x160"
    geometry 128 160 128 160 16
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    nonstd 1
    rgba 5/11,6/5,5/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : fb_st7735r
    Address     : 0
    Size        : 40960
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 0
    YPanStep    : 0
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 256
    Accelerator : No
```

When checking the two SDL environment variables they're set correctly.

It seems that the when i use `/dev/fb1` (the TFT) as the frame buffer device pygame/SDL picks that information up but still can't use it via `pygame`.

Just to mention, i installed the package `python-pygame` via the Raspbian repositories.

The versions of pygame and SDL i'm using:

```
ii  python-pygame                   1.9.1release+dfsg-8
ii  libsdl-image1.2:armhf           1.2.12-2                            
ii  libsdl-mixer1.2:armhf           1.2.12-3                          
ii  libsdl-ttf2.0-0:armhf           2.0.11-2                           
ii  libsdl1.2-dev                   1.2.15-5                       
ii  libsdl1.2debian:armhf           1.2.15-5
```

Comment: What does `fbset -i -fb /dev/fb1` give?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of the command you mentioned! @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: Have you tried specifying the depth manually? `pygame.display.set_mode(size, depth=16)`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
size = width,height = 128,160
```

to

```
size = width,height = 160,128
```

Comment: But the display is 128x160 (Width: 128, Height: 160) and the resolution parameter to set_mode says: _The resolution argument is a pair of numbers representing the width and height._. So `width,height = 128,160` is correct..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself, what i did was to restart the RPi, since then the TFT screen have worked flawlessly with the pygame module.

I think the problem could be found somewhere between Python and the kernel module fbtft that i've been using for this project, or maybe in the way i installed and initialized the kernel module. This is only speculations from my part.

I didn't mention the fact that i was using a third party driver package, stupid of me, there's a small hint that i use these drivers in the dmesg output but nothing more.

I will update the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you were missing the mode item in **/etc/fb.modes** .

I had this issue with a 128x128 display.

You can get the mode via

```
fbset -i
```

And then simply put it's output into **/etc/fb.modes** .

Hope that helps...